# Send data as JSON

Tags: python, json

My server consumes data in JSON format. For test purposes, I have sent POST request by `curl` and by `Postman`. Both POST were correctly received and deserialized by my server. Please have a look at my `curl` command (as I said is is working fine):

```
curl --user trial:trial -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-X POST -d '{"id" : "122"}'  http://localhost:8080/test
```

However, the following [Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49431879/2657875) doesn't seem to send JSON POST correctly:

```
import requests
import json
import sys
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

data = '{"id": "22"}'                           # curl -d
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}  # curl -H
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('trial', 'trial')          # curl -u

req = requests.post(                            # curl -X POST
    'http://localhost:8080/test',
    auth=auth,
    headers=headers)
```

Why is that?

Comment: ...your code doesn't use the `data` variable at all. Maybe that's it?

Comment: The curl command is pointing to `/test` too.

Comment: @Aran-Fey that was silly of me. After adding `data` everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/id', data = {'id': '22'})
```

Full [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/id'
data = '{"id": "22"}' 
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```